# Convert pandas Columns in Rows using (melt doesn't work)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I achieve this in pandas, I have a way where I take out each column as a new data frame and then so a insert in SQL but in that way if I have 10 columns I want to do the same I cannot make 10 data frames so I want to know how can I achieve it dynamically

I have a data set where I have the following data

Output I have

```
Id col1 col2 col3

1  Ab   BC    CD
2  har  Adi   tony
```

Output I want

```
Id col1
1  AB
1  BC
1  CD
2  har
2  ADI
2  Tony
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`melt` **does work**, you just need a few extra steps for the exact output.

Assuming "Id" is a column (if not, `reset_index`).

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Id', value_name='col1')
   .sort_values(by='Id')
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   Id  col1
0   1    Ab
2   1    BC
4   1    CD
1   2   har
3   2   Adi
5   2  tony
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2],
                   'col1': ['Ab', 'har'],
                   'col2': ['BC', 'Adi'],
                   'col3': ['CD', 'tony']})
```

Comment: I added the input I used, make sure it's the same

Comment: Yeah okay cool , that works can you explain me what's happening here?

Comment: What is unclear? Reshape with melt, sort the values, drop the unused column. I suggest you try step by step to see the intermediates.

Comment: Like what is Id_vars means and then why value_name = 'col1' and not 'col2'

Comment: I think you need to read the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html